# static html site, want to apply a server side filter

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, welcome-file

We had a jsp site, that utilized a servlet filter to serve up prerendered html when google bot crawled our site.

WE have now switched to use static html with the entry point defined as the welcome file in the web.xml of a java web application, and all related html and js is contained within the WAR.

However this means the servlet filter never gets hit - how can I work around this ?

Comment: Why is it tagged with `angularjs` seeing there's no mention of `angularjs` issue(s)?

Comment: Also, is the static html page residing in your servlet application?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi because the underlying cause of this problem is due to implementing angular as a one page app. So any people with experience building angular apps will have encountered this or similar problems. Yes the static html is in the java web application.

Comment: Add filter mapping to your file, so it gets hit.

Comment: @RomanC the filter mappings don't get hit as it served as a welcome file

Comment: @NimChimpsky what Roman C is trying to say, why not include the static HTML extension as a Servlet filter mapping and see if this resolves the problem/issue.

Comment: @NimChimpsky welcome files can be used to redirect to a controller.

Comment: @RomanC thanks but I don't want to redirect to a controller

Comment: @BuhakeSindi it doesn't resolve the problem, filters not applied to welcome file

Comment: Does it apply to `*.html` mapping?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi the url pattern of the filter mapping does, but it does not get applied when root called, and the welcome file is used - this is the problem!

Comment: Well, if you want to include all resources in your app, the best `url-pattern` is `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`.

Comment: I think you have to manually call the pattern that matches the filter, after the js has been loaded. Do you already saw [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in angular js?